# how to read file containing Urdu words in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have a text file containing urdu words.

I want to read this file in android. I can only read English words now.

Comment: What is the file encoding? Then just specify that when reading the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert your file to UTF-8, for that you need to open the .txt file with the notepad and then click on File->Save as, over there you can see a dropdown that says Enconding, so change it to UTF-8.

After saving the file you should remove the .txt extension to the file and then add the file to the path res/raw and then you can refer to it from the code as R.raw.txtFileName.

I used some chinese characters and I could show them in the emulator.

**Code Snap:**

```
public List<String> getMyWords() 
{
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.chardb);
        BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        try {
            String line = null;
            while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
                words.add(line);
            }
          }
        finally {
        input.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return words;
}
```

Comment: this code is not displaying Urdu words. it shows only question marks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
this is enabling Unicode supported. So we can handle Unicode strings like multiple language, emoji etc.

You can use the dependency too

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
```

//Fetch From Server and setting to edittext

```
String unicodeString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(serverString);
et_text.setText(unicodeString);
```

//getting from edit text and sending to server

```
String unicodeString = et_text.getText().toString();
String serverString = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(unicodeString);
```

If this couldn't meet your needs please note below

Comment: actually i want to read Urdu text file and display those words in text view in android. this code snippet hasn't help me.